# Does the rate of fire skill affect shotguns?

Tags: front-mission-3

The ROFUP1 skill states it increases number of bullets by 1.2x, does this only work with machine guns or does it affect shot guns too as it also has multiple bullets per shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the skill works with all burst weapon, including Machine guns, Shotguns and Flamethrower.

Answer (score 0):

ZOOM skills are also useful for burst weapons, at least for the first 2/3rds of the game.  Better accuracy equals more hits, more hits equals more damage per turn.  Nice thing about burst weapons compared to Rifles is that they almost always do some damage (unless you use HIT OR MISS skill and miss.  I don't recommend the skill, it just turns your burst weapon into a shorter-range Rifle).  Once your burst weapon accuracy is routinely above 100%, you're better off with ROFUP or AIM skills.  Once you have ROFUP III (which does 2x bullets) you have no need to dual-wield burst weapons, which carries a hefty weight penalty.